# how to display message box with icons in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net-3.5

how to display message box with appropriate icons(such as Warnings/errors/Information etc.) in ASP.NET3.5  using C#

This code doesn't helped.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Data Saved successfully!');", true);
```

Comment: How to show messageBox with SaveAS, Cancel Buttons in ASP.NET

Answer (score 4):

make use of jQuery Dialog or make your own digalog box using javascript.

[**Demos & downloads : Dialog**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: this solution gives the maximum control over how you much you want to stylize the alert message.

Answer (score 1):

A simple look on google for `javascript modal window` will show you some interesting results. [Here's a gallery with some](http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html).

The main idea is to have the content that you want the user to see in a hidden div in the html. Then you add one of those js libraries and trigger the action in a similar way to what you listed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`alert()` will cause your browser to pop up a message, it's impossible to stylize the alert box.

if you'd like to show a custom icon for an alert box you will have to code an 'alert box' of your own - which will actually be a `div` or anything similar

Comment: Pls help me with some suitable XHTML script or equivalent to achieve the same